# How to retrieve WooCommerce Attribute as Taxonomy Term selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have this ACF field:

```
Field Name: brand
Field Type: Taxonomy
Taxonomy: pa_brand
```

[image]

WooCommerce Product Attribute:

```
Name: brand
slug: brand
term id: 51
value: ASUS
```

[image]

I’m trying these codes but it doesn’t work:

```
<?php the_field(‘brand’, $term); ?>

<?php the_field(‘brand’, ‘product_51’); ?>
```

Or how will I know the category to use if I’m wrong.

Answer (score 1):

pass a object to the the_field() method see below code

```
  $obj = get_queried_object();

  the_field(‘brand’, $obj);
```

Comment: I used this:
$brand = get_field_object("brand");
       $term = get_term($brand["value"], "pa_brand");
       echo $brand["value"];

But it's so messy? :D

Comment: How about in this format <?php the_field('field_name', 'category_7'); ?> how?